# AKSZ sigma models for higher spin

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, lie-algebroids

The [AKSZ framework](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AKSZ+sigma-model) constructs 2D sigma models in the BV formalism. Is there a generalization of the AKSZ approach to higher spin?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are after, but the combination of keywords brings this article here to mind:

- K.B. Alkalaev, Maxim Grigoriev, E.D. Skvortsov, *Uniformizing higher-spin equations* [arXiv:1409.6507](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6507)

> **Abstract:** Vasiliev’s higher-spin theories in various dimensions are uniformly represented as a simple system of equations. [...] The proposed system of equations admits
>   a concise AKSZ formulation. [...]

See section 5.